# Magento 2: What is a Resource Model and how can I use it?

Tags: magento-2.1, collection, model, resource-model

In **Magento 1**, using a resource model we are getting collections of data:

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

$category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection');

$order    = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
```

How can I use it in **Magento 2**? Is there any special use of it in this version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**`You can get product,category and order collection by Proper way,`**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,      
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoriesCollection,  
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    array $data = []
)
{    
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;   
    $this->_categoriesCollection = $categoriesCollection;     
    $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
/*
* Product collection Data
*/
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $collection;
}
/*
* Category collection Data
*/
public function getCategoryCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_categoriesCollection->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $collection;
}
/*
* Order collection Data
*/
public function getOrderCollection()
{
    $order = $orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();    
    $order->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
    return $order;
}
```

Now,

> Using Direct Objectmanager is not proper way to do a coding in magento 2.

**`Using objectmanager in template file,`**

```
//get product collection using objectmanager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productCollection->load();
echo "<pre>";print_r($productCollection->getData()); //print product collection

//get category collection using objectmanager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection');
$categoryCollection->load();
echo "<pre>";print_r($categoryCollection->getData()); //print category collection

//get order collection using objectmanager
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection');
$orderCollection->load();
echo "<pre>";print_r($orderCollection->getData()); //print category collection
```

Comment: If i want to call Resourcemodel directly in frontend file without creating my own module then?  Is there any way i can call it directly?

Comment: You can directly call using obejctmanager.

Comment: $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

Comment: let me know if you have still query

Comment: Thanks for brief information about it.  I have one question.   you have written:  $productCollection->load();     What if i want to load product with specific attribute using object manager?  for ex:  product with brand value adidas then?  can i do that using Objectmanger?  is it similar like magento 1 concept?

Comment: $collection->addFieldToFilter('brand',10) and you can do same as m1

Comment: As per the coding standard we can not use objectmanager in magento2  .  it means if i need to product collection filtered by specific attribute then i need to create my own module and through factory method i need to do that?

Answer (score 2):

> Note: As per ECGM2 coding standard you should not use object manager direct in template files

**By ObjectManager**

```
//get product collection
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productCollection->load();
print_r($productCollection->getData()); //print product collection

//get category collection
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categoryCollection->load();
print_r($categoryCollection->getData()); //print category collection

//get order collection
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory');
$orderCollection->load();
print_r($orderCollection->getData()); //print category collection
```

**By Factory Method**

```
public function __construct(
    ...     
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,      
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoriesCollection,  
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;   
    $this->_categoriesCollection = $categoriesCollection;     
    $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
    ...
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $collection; // return product collection
}

public function getCategoryCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->_categoriesCollection->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return $collection; //return category collection
}

public function getOrderCollection()
{
    $order = $orders = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create();
    return $order; //return order collection
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving brief information.  How do i know about other objectmanager methods? i mean you have written:  'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection'    How can i check  what other methods available?    Also, can i filter the collection fetched using object manager ?

Comment: You can use `addAttributeToFilter()`, `addFieldToFilter()`, `setPageSize()`, and other methods same as Magento 1

Comment: Does nobody use the use statement to keep their code clean?

Comment: As per the coding standard we can not use objectmanager in magento2  .  it means if i need to product collection filtered by specific attribute then i need to create my own module and through factory method i need to do that?

Comment: Yes off course you should use Factory method instead of objectManager.